# Packages not found while compiling java

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile my java file to class.
It is a plugin to a much larger program and it runs fine from eclipse when running from source.

I work in Linux, and in shell I type the following `javac MyPlugin.java`

This is just some of the output:

```
MyPlugin.java:11: package javolution.util does not exist
import javolution.util.FastList;
                      ^
MyPlugin.java:12: package javolution.util does not exist
import javolution.util.FastMap;
                      ^
MyPlugin.java:14: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                       ^
MyPlugin.java:15: package org.jwebsocket.api does not exist
import org.jwebsocket.api.PluginConfiguration;
                         ^
```

My assumption is that the rest of the errors are caused because the imports cannot be reached.

Do I need to add something to the original command to have these imports included?

Comment: You need to add those JARs to the classpath.  Consider using Maven.

Comment: Check your Java CLASSPATH: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing jars from the following projects:

http://javolution.org/

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

http://jwebsocket.org/

You can download the missing JARs and include them in your compilation classpath.

Alternatively, you could let [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) manage the download and compilation of your application.

**Update: Gathering all external jars together in one location**

To get all your external libraries in one place you could create a runnable JAR in eclipse using:

```
Export...->Java->Runnable JAR File
```

Enter `your_temp_jar.jar` and click

```
Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR
```

After clicking `Finish` all the required jars will be in a folder called `your_temp_jar_lib`.

Comment: I already have the Jar files from everything I need, that's how eclipse runs them. Can you tell me if there is a way to get all the classpaths eclipse uses so I can use the same ones to compile?

Comment: You can get all the JARS together (see update). Then just build a colon `:` delimited classpath list for your compile.

Comment: Great, that helped a lot. To conclude for future viewers: after I finished doing the above, I altered the command to the as followed: "javac -cp '/path/to/your_temp_jar_lib/*' MyPlugin.java.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the jar files which contains following classes in your classpath.

```
javolution.util.FastList
javolution.util.FastMap
org.apache.log4j.Logger
org.jwebsocket.api.PluginConfiguration
```

you can use `-cp` to specify classpath of jars.

Answer (score 0):

Typing javac at the command line is not a viable or scalable way to build java code. While you could use -cp to javac to add the required dependencies to this compilation, you'd be far better served by learning ant or maven.